# stop publishing bad records in kafka

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I am using apache kafka version 2.6 and have installed confluent only for avro serialisation. I want to know the config changes needed for prompting my kafka consumer to only consume records that are properly serialised at server level itself.

Answer (score 0):

The broker doesn't serialize anything; it only accepts bytes that have already been serialized by the producer. If the consumer doesn't correspond to the producer properties, then you'll have issues.

With Apache Kafka, there is no straightforward way to prevent `SerializationException` on the consumer outside of using `ByteArrayDeserializer` and handling all possible exceptions in the poll loop.

You'd need to prevent badly formatted records at the server-side to gatekeep the producers, for example with [**Confluent Server**](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html), which is an enterprise (paid) offering.